# apply python's sympy function in mathematica

Tags: python

I recently try this
$$\int\frac{\mathop{\rm Si}(x)}x\,dx$$

Mathematica failed to calculate it.

```
Integrate[SinIntegral[x]/x, x]
```

Mma 11.3 failed,but 12.0 can do it.

Sympy gives the answer

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
print(integrate(Si(x)/x, x))
```

x*hyper((1/2, 1/2), (3/2, 3/2, 3/2), -x**2/4)

So I wanted to use the result in Mma.

[image]

I have searched in sympy's document,but still can't find solution.

https://docs.sympy.org/1.0/search.html?q=mathematica&check_keywords=yes&area=default

How can I directly get this function in mathematica?

I saw numpy can be used as follows:(add `import numpy as np` to the beginning,otherwise it will return wrong)

[image]

Which maybe helpful.

**Add:**

[image]

12.0 will return an object.But I temporaily don't know how to use it.(picture is from others)

Comment: Mathematica 12.0 can solve this integral... So why use SymPy?

Comment: @user6014 because it's useful to put several tools together. Besides,I temporarily use 11.3.

Comment: @user6014 Some users may not have access to Mathematica 12.0 yet either, unfortunately. It can be quite expensive.

Comment: Are you interested in sympy-based solutions that work *only* in Mathematica 12.0? Mathematica's Python interface became much better in 12.0.

Comment: @Szabolcs ，So it's very interesting. 11.3 can't solve it, but 12.0 can. 11.3 can't interface with python well, but 12.0 can.Seems the solution is to upgrade to 12.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, you may use Rubi:

```
Get["Rubi`"]
Int[SinIntegral[x]/x, x]
```

> 1/2 x HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, -I x] +   1/2 x
>   HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, I x]

Comment: so it seems like this: 11.3 use Rubi can solve it. 12.0 can solve it directly. 12.0 can also use sympy to solve it.